# Sequelize postgres procedure returns string instead of object

Tags: node.js, postgresql, stored-procedures, sequelize.js

I have stored procedure which makes insert in the end:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION procedure_name(id_ VARCHAR(128), fname_ VARCHAR(128), lname_ VARCHAR(128)) RETURNS RECORD AS $$
DECLARE
      result RECORD;
BEGIN
    --some logic here
    INSERT INTO user (id, fname, lname)
       VALUES (id_, fname_, lname_)
    RETURNING * into result;
    RETURN result;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I run plain INSERT (plain SQL from code):

```
var query = "INSERT INTO user (id, fname, lname) VALUES (2, Jack, Doe) RETURNING *;"
sequelizeConnection.query(query, {raw : true, plain: true, type:sequelizeConnection.QueryTypes.INSERT})
```

result has mapped to object:

```
{
    id: 2,
    fname: Jack,
    lname: Doe
}
```

But when I invoke procedure like this:

```
    function insertUser(data) {
        var options = {replacements: data, raw:true, plain:true,  model:sequelize.models['user'], type: sequelize.QueryTypes.INSERT};
        return sequelize.query("SELECT procedure_name(:id, :fname, :lname)", options);
    }
```

I get following result:

```
{ procedure_name: '(1,John,Doe)'}
```

How to get object from procedure?

Comment: you can try Return sequelize.query("Select * from procedure_name(:id, :fname, :lname)", options)

Comment: Thank you a lot. You are almost right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help of Abdel P. complete answer was found:

```
sequelize.query("Select * from procedure_name(:id, :fname, :lname) as (id VARCHAR(128), fname VARCHAR(128), lname VARCHAR(128))", options)
```